# connect to rtmp server from objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, desktop-application, rtmp

How do i use rtmp protocol for continously watch the server for any changes and when i upload a file to server from my cocoa desktop application?

its already there in lcds. 
I need to notify the user of the app when some new file is uploaded to the ftp. I need to connected to rtmp so that when i upload a file other need to get notification about the file i uploaded. it should a real time.

is there any suggestions or alternatives? it would be a great help.

Thanks a lot in advance :)